# Should I ignore questions that require more info on SU

Tags: discussion, answers

Question [Internet Explorer 10 immediately closes after opening](https://superuser.com/questions/596021/internet-explorer-10-immediately-closes-after-opening) ends with, "What's next?"

More information could lead to a possible solution. Should I do one of the following?

- request more information as a comment to the question
- ignore the question
- flag the question
- give an answer in a non-forum way knowing that could be totally wrong but worth a try

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> request more information as a comment to the question

Yes, if you want to help.

> ignore the question

If you don't want to help.  No one's making you do anything.  I ignore *everything* between 1 am - 7 am and also while working on stuff.

> flag the question

If you are < 3k rep it may make sense to flag to vote to close as not a real question, on the condition that it's not a real question.

> give an answer in a non-forum way knowing that could be totally wrong but worth a try

Probably not.  If you have a pretty good guess what the problem is and want to try posting as an answer then sure.  Be ready to edit or delete if you are far off base, and if this happens even once I would be more conservative going forward.

Answer (score 1):

From comments of the SU question:

> Hi, if you want the OP to clarify certain things please post a comment and not an answer